# Boost Property tree - deal with an empty child

Tags: c++, json, boost

I'm trying to use Boost PropertyTree libary in order to dump some info into an export file.
I've red the documentation but ran into a problem - when assigning an empty property tree as a son, it represents as an empty string and not as an empty dictionary.
I've tried to use a workaround and return an empty_ptree in this case, but it was not helpful.
any suggestions will be much appreciated.

```
Code :
//path = pwd
ptree main;
ptree test1;   
ptree test2;   
test1.put("key", "value")
main.put_child("test1_key", test1);
main.put_child("test2_key", test2);
write_json(path, main)

result :
{
    "test1": {
        "key": "value"
    },
    "test2": ""  //bad - expected it to be a dictionary as well.
}

expected :
result :
{
    "test1": {
        "key": "value"
    },
    "test2": {}
}
```

Comment: Boost PropertyTree is horrible for JSON. It's hardly aware of the differences between the various first class types in JSON and instead will eagerly treat things as the wrong type. Don't use it if you care about using JSON properly. I would recommend using [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) instead.

Comment: thanks @alterigel, I reviewed it and it looks great.